# Mid 2011 iMac 21.5 inch SSD Upgrade how to format disk in terminal

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, imac, disk-utility, ssd

I was wondering how I can erase the SSD disk in terminal to make it show in disk utility. I went into Terminal and typed "diskutil list". The table is as follows:

```
/dev/disk0 (external, physical):
   
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   
1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   
2:                  Apple_HFS Doug's Mac              499.2 GB   disk0s2
   
3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
```

The SSD is identifier disk0 and its type is GUID_partition_scheme, all the rest is the current boot drive and recovery.

What command do I type to format this drive to make it show up in disk utility so I can install my Time Machine Backup on it. It is a WD Blue SSD 3D NAND 500GB Drive.

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but are you going to more trouble than needed? Apple provides the option to start your machine in ["recovery"](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201314) mode, that includes the option to restore from a Time Machine backup.

Comment: I don’t think so. All I’m trying to do is make the SSD readable with Mac OS extended so then I can use my recovery partition and recover from time machine. My time machine drives aren’t currently plugged in to the Mac right now. All that is plugged in is my old drive and a new SSD.

Comment: We need some more info here.  The SSD, is it internal or external?  The disk that is showing up (`disk0`) is already formatted.  That doesn't look like a time machine backup.  How is this new SSD installed?